# Firestore function with Promises.all takes very long to complete

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I am new to javascript, and I am pretty sure the code is less than ideal. I am running into some issues getting the data from Firestore.

The personalMessage function takes around 50 seconds to complete, and I a have no idea why it takes so long. 
This code in swift will return from the database under 1000ms.

Also any pointers in code style is recommended.

[image]

```
function sendMessageToDevice(token, payload, options) {
  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload, options)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Successfully sent message:', response, response.results[0].error);
      return response
    })
    .catch(error =>  console.log('Error sending message:', error));
}

function getUser(userId) {
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            if (!snapshot.exists) {
                console.log('No such document!');
                return null;
            }
            return snapshot.data()
        })

        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting document', err);
            return err;
        });
}


exports.personalMessage = functions.firestore
    .document('/messages/{id}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      var messageData = snapshot.data();
      var userId = messageData.user;
      var fromId = messageData.from;

      Promise.all([getUser(userId), getUser(fromId)])

      .then(([dataA, dataB]) => {
          console.log(dataA.fcmToken, dataB.name);


          var payload = {
             notification: {
                 title: dataB.name + ' messaged you.',
                 body: 'Go check it out it',
                 clickAction: 'NEW_PERSONAL_MESSAGE'},
             data: {
                 messageId: context.params.id}
             };

          var options = {
              contentAvailable: false,
              priority: 'high'
          }

          return sendMessageToDevice(dataA.fcmToken, payload, options);
      })



      .catch(error =>  console.log('Error sending message:', error));

      return Promise.resolve('success');
});
```

Comment: The log you're showing says the function executes in 3.4 seconds, not 50 seconds.  Also, you're not using promises correctly.  The function as shown will return immediately and not wait for any of the async work to complete, which means it's possible that none of it will complete.

Comment: Thank you Doug, for the quick response. As you see I am still struggling with this. Successfully sent message is only executed 50 seconds later, why is there this delay? 
How would I use Promises correctly then? I have checked out your firecasts videos which helped, but apparently I'm still missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doug talk about the incorrect promises. I change a little in your code. 
However, the message may be not come immediately for some reason like network,...

```
function sendMessageToDevice(token, payload, options) {
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload, options)

}

function getUser(userId) {
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get()

}


exports.personalMessage = functions.firestore
    .document('/messages/{id}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      var messageData = snapshot.data();
      var userId = messageData.user;
      var fromId = messageData.from;

      return Promise.all([getUser(userId), getUser(fromId)])
      .then(result=> {

            if (!result[0].exists || !result[1].exists) {
                console.log('No such document!');
                return null;
            }
            return [result[0].data(),result[1].data()]
        }) 
      .then(([dataA, dataB]) => {
          console.log(dataA.fcmToken, dataB.name);


          var payload = {
             notification: {
                 title: dataB.name + ' messaged you.',
                 body: 'Go check it out it',
                 clickAction: 'NEW_PERSONAL_MESSAGE'},
             data: {
                 messageId: context.params.id}
             };

          var options = {
              contentAvailable: false,
              priority: 'high'
          }

          return sendMessageToDevice(dataA.fcmToken, payload, options);
      })
      .then(response => {
          console.log('Successfully sent message:', response, 
               response.results[0].error);
          return Promise.resolve('success');
      }) 
      .catch(error =>  console.log('Error sending message:', error));

});
```

Comment: Hi Tora! Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate the effort. In the functions above, you removed the .then .catch is it because they return a Promise anyways? Could you maybe elaborate some of the changes, so I can understand better what you did? In anyway I am grateful thank you

Comment: Like doug said, your **sendMessageToDevice** is just run the promise with then and catch like the function, not the promise. So when the main function run, it will pass out (not waiting) for that function and that may get your function shutdown without **sendMessageToDevice** finish. Same as your *Promise.all*.
Basically, I tried to follow the rule **promise/always-return** with every **then** return a **promise** or **throw** and **promise/no-nesting** with not accept **child promise+then** in **parent promise.then** in eslint.

Comment: You can check the rule in here: https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/tree/master/docs/rules

Comment: The tip is if you want to do your work sequence with promise, just use `then` whenever you `return` a promise.